# How can I make pandas stop skipping first blank column in TSV file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

When importing a tab-delimited data file (TSV) using `pandas.read_csv()`, I get back a dataframe with the right column names (and thus the right number of columns), but it appears to have shifted the data from each column to the left by 1. This also results in the final, rightmost column being all `NaN` values.

I suspect this is because the first column is completely blank in the TSV file (I believe the creator of the file used `None` as the values for this column in python and then made the file with `df.to_csv()`). How do I import the data such that my dataframe ends up with the first column being all `NaN`, which is what I want whenever a column has blank values in it?

My use case for this involves **a lot** of these TSV files, some of which will have blank `charge_code` columns but some in which this column will have meaningful data. As such, I need a dynamic solution that can check for the blank nature of the column and then set it all to `NaN` automatically.

**A sample of the data file:**

```
    6   MISOPROSTOL, ORAL, 200 MCG  kaiser-foundation-southern-region   106191300_CDM_2018.xlsx standard
    13  DIALYSIS/STRESS VITAMIN SUPL ORAL 100 CAPSULES  kaiser-foundation-southern-region   106191300_CDM_2018.xlsx standard
    30  PRENATAL VITAMINS 30-DAY SUPPLY kaiser-foundation-southern-region   106191300_CDM_2018.xlsx standard
    50  COMP CONT LENS EVAL kaiser-foundation-southern-region   106191300_CDM_2018.xlsx standard
```

**The code I'm trying to use to import:**

```
pd.read_csv('problem_lines.tsv', delimiter = r'\t',
            header = None,
            names = ['charge_code', 'price', 'description', 'hospital_id',
                    'filename', 'charge_type'], 
            index_col = False)
```

**And the code's output:**

```
charge_code price   description hospital_id filename    charge_type
0   6.0 MISOPROSTOL, ORAL, 200 MCG  kaiser-foundation-southern-region   106191300_CDM_2018.xlsx standard    NaN
1   13.0    DIALYSIS/STRESS VITAMIN SUPL ORAL 100 CAPSULES  kaiser-foundation-southern-region   106191300_CDM_2018.xlsx standard    NaN
2   30.0    PRENATAL VITAMINS 30-DAY SUPPLY kaiser-foundation-southern-region   106191300_CDM_2018.xlsx standard    NaN
3   50.0    COMP CONT LENS EVAL kaiser-foundation-southern-region   106191300_CDM_2018.xlsx standard    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `charge_code` column to be NaNs then set it after you read like so:

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('problem_lines.tsv', delimiter = r'\t',
        header = None,
        names = ['price', 'description', 'hospital_id',
                'filename', 'charge_type'], 
        index_col = False)

df['charge_code'] = np.nan
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned that I'm going to be reading in a lot of these TSV files, and some of them will not have blank `charge_code` columns, so I need something that can dynamically deal with the blank-ness.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, I think I've figured it out. I changed the raw string for the delimiter into a regular string and now, for some reason, it works. I must admit, I'm a little bothered that I don't totally understand *why* it works, so if you have any suggestions I'd love to hear them!

**New functioning code:**

```
pd.read_csv('problem_lines.tsv', delimiter = '\t',
            header = None,
            names = ['charge_code', 'price', 'description', 'hospital_id',
                    'filename', 'charge_type'], 
            index_col = False)
```